# How to calculate roughness contour in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, contour, feature-extraction

Is there a way to calculate roughness contour in opencv?

image sample: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2NDgySmJ6NnpId0U/edit?usp=sharing

**UPDATE**

My code for calculating roughness:

perimeter contour/ convex hull perimeter

```
nomeimg = 'Riscalate2/JPEG/e (5).jpg'

img = cv2.imread(nomeimg)

gray = cv2.imread(nomeimg,0)#convert grayscale adn binarize

element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(6,6)) 
graydilate = cv2.erode(gray, element) #imgbnbin

cv2.imshow('image',graydilate)
cv2.waitKey(0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(graydilate,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)   # binarize

imgbnbin = thresh
cv2.imshow('bn',thresh)
cv2.waitKey()

#element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(2,2))
#element = np.ones((11,11),'uint8')


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgbnbin, cv2.RETR_TREE ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contours))


# Take only biggest contour basing on area
Areacontours = list()
calcarea = 0.0
unicocnt = 0.0
for i in range (0, len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    #print("area")
    #print(area)
    if (area > 90 ):  #con 90 trova i segni e togli puntini
        if (calcarea<area):
            calcarea = area
            unicocnt = contours[i]

#ROUGHNESS
perimeter = cv2.arcLength(unicocnt,True)
hull = cv2.convexHull(unicocnt,returnPoints = False)
hullperimeter = cv2.arcLength(hull,True)

print("perimeter")
print(perimeter)
print("hullperimeter")
print(hullperimeter)


roughness = perimeter/hullperimeter
print("roughness")
print(roughness)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\nuovefeature.py", line 417, in <module>
    hullperimeter = cv2.arcLength(hull,True)
error: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1886: error: (-215) curve.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (curve.depth() == CV_32F || curve.depth() == CV_32S)
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried, and what research you have done so far.

Comment: or add an image and explain what you expect as output?

Comment: I do not try anithink, professor asked me if there is a function that measure roughness contour like in matlab.

Comment: Try convexityDefects and isContourConvex.

Comment: I tried but then i saw that for calculating roughness is perimeter contour/perimeter convex hull  but hullperimeter = cv2.arcLength(hull,True) i get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\nuovefeature.py", line 417, in <module>
    hullperimeter = cv2.arcLength(hull,True)
error: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1886: error: (-215) curve.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (curve.depth() == CV_32F || curve.depth() == CV_32S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the convexHull finding line.

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(unicocnt,returnPoints = False)
```

By default, the flag `returnPoints` is `True`. Then the hull returned contains the pixel coordinates of hull points or contour points. It is normally used for drawing hull, finding its area, perimeter etc.

But if you specify it as `False`, the values returned are the indices of those coordinates in contour. It is normally used for finding convexityDefects.

So your code should be like below :

```
hull = cv2.convexHull(unicocnt)
```

For more detailed explanation with examples, please read convexHull section in [**`this article`.**](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/contours-2-brotherhood.html)